# Align heading of thebibliography within currvita environment

Tags: bibliographies, currvita

I'm using currvita in a scrartcl and I'd like to put in a publication section like so:

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[]{currvita}
\begin{document}
    \center
    \begin{cv}{Name}
        \begin{thebibliography}{}
            \bibitem{} Interesting publication
        \end{thebibliography}
    \end{cv}
\end{document}
```

Gives[image]
I'm trying to figure out how to left-align the title 'Publications' of the bibliography section, but due to the combination of scrartcl, currvita and bibliography related info online I'm not really sure where to start looking.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using **biblatex** instead of **bibtex**, the problem gets solved automatically:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[]{currvita}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{reference.bib}
    @article{Orwell,
        author  = "George Orwell and Aldous Huxley and William Shakespeare and Oscar Wilde",
        title   = "1984",
        year    = "1948",
        journal = "Books about big brothers",
        volume  = "5",
        number  = "42",
        pages   = "100--111"
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}

\setkomafont{subsection}{\small\rmfamily}
\defbibheading{main}{\subsection*{Publications}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{Orwell}

    \center
    \begin{cv}{Name}
        \printbibliography[heading=main]
    \end{cv}
\end{document}
```

The heading can be customized with `\defbibheading` and `\setkomafont`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The result is independent from KOMA-Script. It is because of the redefinition of `thebibliography` by `currcita` inside the `cv` environment. Nevertheless, while using a KOMA-Script class it would be enough to restore the original `thebibliography`:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd{\cv}{%
  \let\origthebibliography\thebibliography
  \let\endorigthebibliography\endthebibliography
}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\cv}{%
  \let\thebibliography\origthebibliography
  \let\endthebibliography\endorigthebibliography
}{}{}
```

Now, you can configure `thebibliography` as described in the KOMA-Script manual, e.g., using option `headings=small`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[]{currvita}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd{\cv}{%
  \let\origthebibliography\thebibliography
  \let\endorigthebibliography\endthebibliography
  \KOMAoptions{headings=small}%
}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\cv}{%
  \let\thebibliography\origthebibliography
  \let\endthebibliography\endorigthebibliography
}{}{}

\begin{document}
    \center
    \begin{cv}{Name}
      \begin{origthebibliography}{}
            \bibitem{} Interesting publication
        \end{origthebibliography}
    \end{cv}
\end{document}
```

[image: with headings=small]

or additional `bibliography=leveldown`:

[image: additional bibliography=leveldown]

or even using `\RedeclareSectionCommand`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt,bibliography=leveldown]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[]{currvita}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd{\cv}{%
  \let\origthebibliography\thebibliography
  \let\endorigthebibliography\endthebibliography
  \RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=1sp,afterskip=1sp,font=\cvheadingfont]{subsection}%
}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\cv}{%
  \let\thebibliography\origthebibliography
  \let\endthebibliography\endorigthebibliography
}{}{}

\begin{document}
    \center
    \begin{cv}{Name}
      \begin{origthebibliography}{}
            \bibitem{} Interesting publication
        \end{origthebibliography}
    \end{cv}
\end{document}
```

[image: with \cvheadingfont]